# CriteriaBuilder query with Like between two columns

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to create a query using CriteriaBuilder where I need to compare two columns using a *like*.

(**Showing only relevant parts of the code**)

The query is built like this: `builder.like(column1, column2);` where `column1` and `column2` are both of type `Expression`.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to add the wildcard character to the query. This is the generated query:

```
where saldodocum.NU_DOCUMENTO_ORIGINAL like substring(saldodocum.NU_DOCUMENTO, 5, 3)
```

And what I need is:

```
where saldodocum.NU_DOCUMENTO_ORIGINAL like '%' + substring(saldodocum.NU_DOCUMENTO, 5, 3) + '%'
```

Is there a way to achieve this using CriteriaBuilder? I cannot add `%` to `column2` since I'm using the column name and not a set value.

Comment: can you show what do you pass over to column2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`builder.like(column1, builder.concat("%",builder.concat(column2,"%"));`

Comment: Thanks, this does it. I overlooked the concat function thinking it did something else, should've looked more carefully!